# How to combine lines of a single text file in python?

Tags: python, combinatorics, python-itertools

I've searched, but found nothing to help.. This is an example:

```
    List.txt
    a
    b
    c
    d
```

I want to be able to get an output like this:

```
    Output.txt
    ab
    ac
    ad
    ba
    bc
    bd
    ca
    cb
    cd
    etc...
```

Comment: Can you provide the algorithm/repetition format for exactly what you want done?

Comment: You will get more help if you show us what you've tried, so people can get a better understanding of where you're getting hung up.

Comment: Is this a Homework problem? If so, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straightforward...

```
from itertools import permutations

with open('List.txt') as f:    
    letters = (l.strip() for l in f if l.strip())    
    for p in permutations(letters, 2):
        print ''.join(p)
```

Output:

```
ab
ac
ad
ba
bc
bd
ca
cb
cd
da
db
dc
```

Some notes:

The `with` statement ensures the file will be closed when you're done with it.

`letters` is a generator expression, which in many cases (though not this one) will save you from having to read the entire file in at once.

The uses of `l.strip()` are meant to nicely handle accidental blank lines if present in input.

`itertools.permutations` is correct, NOT `itertools.combinations` which considers `ab` == `ba` and will not include the latter as output.

Happy pythoning :)

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("List.txt")
lines = f.read().splitlines()
lines_new = []
for line in lines:
    for line2 in lines:
        if not line == line2:
            lines_new.append("%s%s" % (line, line2))

print lines_new # ['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ba', 'bc', 'bd', 'ca', 'cb', 'cd', 'da', 'db', 'dc']
open("Output.txt", "w").write("\n".join(lines_new))
```

Results in a file called Output.txt with:

```
ab
ac
ad
ba
bc
bd
ca
cb
cd
da
db
dc
```

Answer (score 0):

The *itertools* module has combinatoric functions to help with problems like this one:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, permutations, product
>>> s = open('list.txt').read().splitlines()
>>> for t in permutations(s, 2):
        print ''.join(t)
```

Comment: In this case, you would need `itertools.permutations`, consider `map(''.join, permutations('abcd',2))` vs `map(''.join, combinations('abcd',2))` compared to the desired output.

Answer (score -1):

You can first read the file into an array:

```
lines=[]
for line in file:
  lines.append(line)
```

and then iterate over it to get the desired output.

```
for line1 in lines:
  for line2 in lines:
    print line1+line2
```

or print it to a file instead.